# Help on choosing box-style hinge for a chess board

Tags: hinges

I am looking for some nice rectangular hinges for use on a folding chess board. They need to fold 180 degrees and be flush to the bottom.

To do that, the knuckle needs to be mortised into the wood along with the leaf. That means the mortise depth is that of the knuckle, leaving the leaf lower than flush and leaving visible about half of the sides of the mortise. I think this does not look very good.

Are there any hinges that are designed to avoid this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExhange. It's not actually the case that the mortise needs to equal the thickness of the knuckle, but if it did why does it matter? This is on the underside of the box when in use so normally nobody will be looking at it. Plus anyway, woodworkers tend to be fussy about this sort of thing when normal people often wouldn't notice :-) But that said, weirdly (for me) it seems that many commercial chess sets hide the hinge with a flap of the baize o_O Note that metal hinges aren't the only option, you could use a flexible 'hinge' (leather or a suitable cloth) in this application

Comment: Don't forget the classic wood hinge. I think Rob Cosman has an entire video series on making these.

Comment: @jdv, yeah good point. Yes Rob Cosman does have one or more vids on wooden hinges, but the problem with that is having to watch a Rob Cosman video, or worse, more than one LOL

Comment: @Graphus he's an acquired taste, maybe! I get him mostly, as he has an east-coast Canuck demeanour I'm familiar with. I use him as a good reference in contrast with Rex Krueger and Paul Sellers and then do what I want anyway! I'm more likely to sharpen like Sellers but Cosman has a lot of stealable tricks up his sleeve. (And the wood hinge would be _perfect_ for this project AFAICT)

Comment: That's a good point that the mortise depth could be just the leaf depth. The knuckle would then protrude above the board. Another aesthetic decision, although you now might scratch other surfaces with the hinge.

Comment: On second thought that won't work. The knuckle will protrude preventing the open chess board from resting flat on a surface.

Comment: @jdv, *"I use him as a good reference in contrast with Rex Krueger and Paul Sellers and then do what I want anyway!"* Hehe +1. *"but Cosman has a lot of stealable tricks up his sleeve"* Yeah that's true enough, although I wish (like with Sellers) he wouldn't attribute them to himself so much! What first put me off him was a sharpening demo years ago where I literally stopped watching mid-sentence, after he had insisted that only his level of sharpening was acceptable, which is BS. But since then I've heard of plenty that would put me off him, including and by no means least the naked shilling.

Comment: I think the ideal solution is the butler hinge style, but in a rectangular format, if there is such a thing.

Comment: By a complete coincidence a friend of mine came across an old folding chess set yesterday while going through a storage box! The hinge knuckle sits above the playing surface when the board is unfolded, which is exactly what I thought I remembered from my cheapie (plastic pieces, Formica? top) folding chess set I had as a kid.

Comment: I found these card table hinges (correct name for this hinge style) might also work. They are still long, but quite narrow (1/2"). They would have to be used at the ends of the box, which might not be ideal for strength. https://www.leevalley.com/en-ca/shop/hardware/table-hardware/40574-narrow-flip-top-hinges?item=00H3801